Load for 4x6 Douglass fir 8’ long drop in bathtub
We’re re-modeling an old bathroom.
I need to frame out a drop in tub. We need it to support at least 1,000 lb.
Will a 4x6x8 beam, Douglas fir support that load?

That's a pretty puny beam by modern standards--think of it as a pair of 2x6s, which aren't even usually considered a beam-sized member. Please revise to describe the overall floor framing strategy more clearly. The beam isn't the only consideration.

It also depends how this beam is supposed to support the tub.  Is the beam supposed to support the tub deck?  The bottom?  Longitudinally, or laterally?
